# A less cumbersome way to specify encoding when opening encoded text files

Tags: encoding, openoffice-writer

In order to open an encoded text file with the correct encoding in `OO Writer`, the user goes through *File>Open*, then selects *'Text Encoded'* from a long list of file types, which causes a dialog to pop up with another list of encoding filters; after choosing one, the file opens with the desired encoding.

First this is very cumbersome, second it nullifies shortcuts like *'open recent files'*, or in a file manager *'open file with OO Writer'*.

Is there a way to do any of: **set default encoding for opening text files**, or, **change encoding for currently open file**?